# Keras custom loss with 3D output

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I am trying to implement the network described in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04110

And I am wondering how to create a custom loss function (in my case a negative binomial) which takes which has two y_pred parameters which are being estimated by the network. A simple example (network not as shown in paper but just for the purpose of asking this question):

```
n_neurons = 256
n_batch = 100
n_epochs = 50
gru_cells=128
dense_units = 20


encoder_input_data_train = np.random.randn(100, 10, 2)
X2_train = np.random.randn(100, 10, 1)
target = np.random.randn(100, 10, 1)

inputs = Input(shape=(encoder_input_data_train.shape[1], 
encoder_input_data_train.shape[2]))
aux_inputs  = Input(shape=(X2_train.shape[1], X2_train.shape[2]))
encoder = GRU(gru_cells, input_shape=(None,), return_sequences=True)(inputs)
cat = k.layers.concatenate([encoder, aux_inputs])
tdist = TimeDistributed(Dense(dense_units, activation='relu'))(cat)
dropout = Dropout(0.5)(tdist)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(2))(dropout)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs, aux_inputs], outputs=[out])
model.compile(loss=[nb_loss()], optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit([encoder_input_data_train, X2_train],
                    target, 
                    epochs=n_epochs,
                    batch_size=n_batch,
                    validation_split=0.20,
                    verbose=1,
                     callbacks=[k.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2)])
```

My attempt at writing the loss is:

```
def nb_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    eps = 1e-10
    y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true, axis=2)
    y_pred = y_pred[:, :]

    alpha = y_pred[:, :, 0]
    alpha = 1. / (alpha + eps)

    mu = y_pred[:, :, 1]

    t1 = -tf.lgamma(y_true + alpha + eps)
    t2 = tf.lgamma(alpha + eps)
    t3 = tf.lgamma(y_true + 1.0) 

    t4 = -(alpha * (tf.log(alpha + eps)))
    t5 = -(y_true * (tf.log(mu + eps)))
    t6 = (alpha + y_true) * tf.log(alpha + mu + eps)

    loss = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5 + t6

    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

However when I run it throws a TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
Anyone have experience writing custom loss functions such as this?

Comment: Try squeezing `y_true` outside the loss function. This part is causing an error as it is removing `batch_dimension` which is `None`.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko, you're absolutely correct, if I add `axis=2` as a parameter to `tf.squeeze()` the loss function works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's great - may I formulate the answer?

Comment: Sure, that would be helpful. Another problem I'm having now is that is is returning loss of nan. I'm generating samples by pulling from a negative binomial distribution meaning that it has lots of zeros, which I try to offset by adding the esp constant to values but can't seem to get it to return values.

Comment: Ok, after debugging my loss function using first a combination of numpy and math.lgamma, and then using using keras.backend.eval(), I got it returning good losses. I've edited my question to include the updated negative binomial loss. Thanks again for the help!